# tabs on both sides of Jtabbed pane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I want my Jtabbed pane to have tabs on both left and right side,is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: The same tab pane or different tabs?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a scary interface. A better solution might be buttons on the left and right with a card layout in the center.  If I saw tabs on both sides, it would look really confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

no, that's not supported (and probably shouldn't, as jzd already noted :-). If you insist, you'll have to implement a custom component: look into the sources of JTabbedPane and its ui-delegate (BasicTabbedPaneUI) for inspiration.